# Upgrade SPF'x to 1.6.0

Tags: sharepoint, adal.js, spfx

In a solution I had 2 SPF'x web parts and 3 SPF'x Extensions. I need to upgrade the web part to SPF'x 1.6.0. So I have updated my package.json references to 1.6.0. Then I had ran the "npm install" command. Once I done both these, it throws the below error.

> ...\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@m icrosoft\node-core-library\lib\JsonSchema.js:178 throw new Error(prefix + os.EOL + ^
>
> Error: JSON validation failed: D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\config\tslint.json
>
> Error: #/ (Defines configuration options for the...) Additional properties not allowed: lintConfig,useDefaultConfigAsBase,remo veExistingRules,displayAsWarning at validateObjectWithCallback".

Am I missing anything? What is the proper way to upgrade the solution to SPF'x 1.6.0?

Comment: Please let us know if you got fix, I am also getting same error.

Comment: Yes. I got a fix. Check this post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248853/updating-spfx-breaks-gulp/248901#248901